# Where in the rulebook does it explain how to use Wises?

Tags: burning-wheel

In [Why I Love the Burning Wheel, at about 39 minutes in](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E79DDGdX62I&t=2343) the author explains that Wises can be used either to ask for information about the world *or* to *make stuff up wholesale*.

Consulting the rulebook, I can see on page 309 that Wises are described as skills through which a character can call upon their knowledge of the world, but I can't find any reference to the skill allowing you to actually help *shape* that world.

Can someone direct me to the part of the rulebook that goes into that? Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The *Burning Wheel Codex* has a whole section on Wises.  From the first paragraph:

> ...wises are a key way for the players to put their own stamp on the
> setting. This is implicit in the core Burning Wheel rules but perhaps
> not quite as apparent as it should be.

I would say that last point is an understatement.

The section continues with some examples, but they basic idea seems to be: If a player uses a Wise to suggest a piece of lore, and it doesn't contradict the GM's planned lore, a Wise test can be used to determine whether the player's suggestion is actually true.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what's in the latest revision, but the piece that comes to mind is the chapter on Wises in the (sadly) out-of-print Adventure Burner.

I think different groups will handle this differently, somewhere on a spectrum with, "Yeah, this gives players total narrative control!" at one end. My sense is that wises (like circles) is just a codification of something that happens at a lot of fairly traditional tables, even in D&D.

GM: You enter the tavern, it's dark and smoky. The atmosphere seems tense.
Player 1: I lived in this town.. would I know anybody here? I'm looking for someone w
GM: Um, sure.. like who?
Player 1: Well, is there a town drunk, maybe?

Other games leave this up to the table culture or imply that the GM should answer these, while BW adds a mechanic to resolve the tension between plausibility, creative participation and advantage-seeking.